# Monitor Hard drive for new files created

Tags: windows, monitoring, filesystemwatcher, hard-drive, vista64

I am not sure if there is any utility which monitors hard drive for any new files getting created.

I am using one application that creates many files on my hard drive but I am not sure how can I monitor those newly created files.

BTW I am using Windows VISTA x64 machine.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Review your other questions and accept some answers.

Comment: @Paulo I mean I wanted a notification of newly created files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760904

Comment: @karlphilip sorry for bad way of asking questions - I am working on that :(

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In native code, use a [directory change notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If you prefer .net, then use [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you are a programmer and know Python, you should check https://fascinator.usq.edu.au/trac/wiki/Watcher

It monitors folders/directory for file changes i.e. created, deletion, modification.

If you are a Java Programmer, you should check WatchService in JDK 7. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 0):

Check  out the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class. It will help you by notifying you when something in a particular directory has changed.