# Windows Service- check a folder every x seconds

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am wanting to create a Windows Service for the first time, but just have a question about the logic of it:

I want to create a service that every x seconds, poll's a directory, reads all the text files in this directory, inserts the details into the database and then archives this file.

How do I do this so that it runs every x seconds? (which x is defined in a configuration file).

Do I do a loop that says something like:

```
int interval = 5000;
while (TRUE) {
   //my logic
   Thread.Sleep(interval); //pause for 5 seconds
}
```

Is this the accepted method to achieve this?

Comment: Remember to lock (no pun) files etc if the service runs more than 5 seconds. Alternatively look a FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FileSystemWatcher` instead of checking every x seconds.You will be notified whenever a file or folder in the given folder is created,deleted or changed

Check [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) from msdn.

Comment: This sounds like a much better solution than a timer!

Answer (score 1):

Alliteratively, you can you the `FileSystemWatcher` API. It trigger an event when the folder changes. This save your battery life if you are on laptop.

[How can I monitor a Windows directory for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760904/how-can-i-monitor-a-windows-directory-for-changes)