# File system filter driver for specific file types

Tags: c#, c++, windows, file-io, filter-driver

I need to detect when either of two file types are accessed in any way across an entire windows file system.

As I understand it the only way to do this without causing serious slow downs for the operating system is to create a file system filter driver?

Essentially all I need to do is take a copy of any doc(x) files and pdf's that are opened. I decided on this approach as it was either that or use file monitors in C# which wouldn't be effective for an entire drive.

My question is two fold, is there an easier way and secondly how would I go about simply taking a copy of each doc(x)/pdf file as it's accessed?

The solution needs to be deployable with the package we're currently producing.

UPDATE

I'm going to benchmark the file system watcher, after discussing it with people here I think it's possible that it may be acceptable, my concern is the fact that I need to monitor the common user directories where downloads will occur( so "C:\Users\SomeUser*" as well as the outlook temporary folder.

Comment: The only thing a file system driver will buy you is a way to throttle the updates so you can deal with a firehose problem.  But such a driver creates the problem you explicitly don't like, serious system slowdowns.  Your requirement is a very odd one, creating a copy only when the file is accessed.  You can't even do that with FSW, it was made to detect changes.  A sensible alternative is to *always* have a copy.  You should be looking into the Volume Shadow Copy service.

Comment: if you are producing the package opening these files, why cant it make a copy when it goes to open a file?

Comment: Hi guys essentially the software needs a copy of documents as they arrive on the OS, I suppose I could look to monitor the entry points rather than the entire OS, IE outlook temp folder, downloads folder etc...

Comment: http://esmithy.net/2006/07/21/file-system-monitoring/ may get you to the answer that you are looking for.  Have you considered WinAPI (PInvoke) perhaps?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215619/detect-when-a-directory-or-file-changes may also do the trick.

Comment: You also need to define what you mean exactly by "file accessed", or "file opened"? For example, the way Notepad opens a file is very different from the way Word opens the same file, from a point of view that focuses only on what happens in the file system. Just setup FSW on a directory, test notepad and word on a .txt file and you'll see the notifications stream is very very different from one app to another when you just "open" or "access" it. Notepad creates a copy only if you save it, Word creates a lot of temp files, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a file system watcher. Here is a code example that will watch for changes to docx files.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace filewatchtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run();
        }

        [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
        public static void Run()
        {
            string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

            // if directory not specified then end program
            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: filewatchtest.exe directory");
                return;
            }

            // create a new fileSystemWatcher and set its properties
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = args[1];

            // set the notify filters
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            // set the file extension filter
            watcher.Filter = "*.docx";

            // add event handlers
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

            // bengin watching
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // wait for the user to quit the program
            Console.WriteLine("Plress q to quit the program");
            while (Console.Read()!='q');


        }

        static void OnRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
        }

        static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {            
            Console.WriteLine("File:" + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your answer unfortunately using a filesystem on entire drive would be terribly slow i'd think no?

Comment: On top of that LastAccess is disabled now with windows file systems hence me mentioning above it'll probably not work very well!

Comment: Sorry just reread my last comment and it came off a bit rude, I am grateful for your suggestion but I don't think FS watcher will work well.

Comment: @MrkFldig: Why not simply try? A FSW is not that hard to implement. Just give it a shot and check if it meets your performance needs.

Comment: Hi Andrew i'm awarding you the 50 since you got here first.

Comment: Sorry andrew I just noticed that I hadn't awarded! Better late than never!

Answer (score 2):

I think that creating a copy on read will cause a lot of problems. For instance: virus scanners. Consider the following:

1. I open file "test.pdf"
2. Your program creates "test_copy.pdf"
3. Virus scanner detects new file and checks (reads) "test_copy.pdf"
4. Your program detects read access, and creates "test_copy_copy.pdf"
5. Virus scanner...

Now you ofcourse you could create copies with a different extension to prevent this, but still there will be a lot of `READ` actions on files. I sometimes open a file like 10 times, just because I closed it accidentally or I want to recheck something I just read. Now you'll have 10 copies?

I would definitly go with Hans Passant's suggestion of creating a copy on change/create. That happens a lot less by definition, because you always need to open it to alter it, but don't have to alter it when you open it.

The second problem would be to detect a read to a file. Now with `docx` you could check for the creation of hidden files like '~$_____.docx', but that doesn't work for `PDF`. Also like you mentioned, you will have to check an entire disk. There is no way around it. If a file can be in any folder, you'll have to check all the folders. Creating an internal list of `docx` and `PDF` files in a service could be faster, but as you'll have to loop trough each file again at set intervals it depends on how many files are on the system.

So if you really need to check `read access`, a file system driver is all you got. But since it will be called on every file access, causing problems or slow systems would be a mayor concern.

If you still want to, check out this [File System Filter Driver Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial) to learn how to do it. Personally, I wouldn't go there.

Comment: Actually what I need to do is notice a new file and upload it from our "tray" application to a web service.

Comment: So you're building dropbox with a system wide drop folder? Then just use a file system watcher for create and changed events and upload it.

Comment: Can you even do a file system watcher across an entire drive?

Comment: Sure, but I'd recommend reading about the memory usage http://stackoverflow.com/q/13916595/434949

Comment: Thanks for that what i'm coming round to is maybe I should just find a way of monitoring open file handles since I only need to know when someone opens a PDF or word doc? OR I wonder if it's possible to associate two programs with one file type, ie double click a word doc and it fires off to my process AND word..

Comment: If you can force your user to change the way docx/pdf opens, you could have them open it in one of your processes and your process opens the file in the actual viewer. But still, you shouldn't be checking for opening files, but for changing and then a file system watcher is what you want. Everything else you try to come up with will be slower or requires you to have full control over the computer the users use.

Comment: Hrm, from the looks of it you can use WMI to hook into a process start event which doesn't seem to have much impact on system resources, its definitely better than trying to setup a file system watcher to keep an eye on an entire drive no?

Comment: I guess that would be dodgy at best. What do you want to track then? Process start doesn't mean read file and i'm sure Word can open a file without starting a new proces

Answer (score 1):

From what I read in the comments, a File System Watcher would probably work well. I am not exactly sure whether [Search Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) uses one, but if it does, I cannot notice any impact.

Another option might be [ETW - Windows Event Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as used by [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Even with millions of changes, I can also hardly notice the impact.

I you want to go for Volume Shadow Copies as proposed by Hans Passant, [Alpha Volume Shadow Copies](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaVSS) might be a suitable library offering support for it.

Conclusion: a filter driver is probably not needed and keeps you away from other problems, although I admit that the description of *hierarchical storage management systems* might match your approach, thinking of the upload store as the next hierarchy after hard disk.