# Script: To automatic move files from 1 folder to another

Tags: xcopy

I would like to have a script to monitor a folder and when a .mp3 or .m4a file is added it would be automatic copy it to another folder.

Comment: I assume you are using Windows as your OS? What programming languages are available to use? Look at the similar answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760904/how-can-i-monitor-a-windows-directory-for-changes and http://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created

Answer (score 3):

This can be done simply with PowerShell. I have assumed that you would like the copied file to be removed from the source directory so that any file in the source directory hasn't been copied yet.

The statement `start-sleep -s 30` pauses for 30 seconds.

```
for (;;) {
    start-sleep -s 30
    move-item c:\source\*.mp3 c:\destination
    move-item c:\source\*.m4a c:\destination
}
```

Comment: To start a Powershell script you can store it anywhere, then call it by filename (using a .ps1 extension). You can also use something like the Windows Powershell ISE and hitting "F5". If you want it to run all the time the computer is running, I think it would work to put the script in the Startup folder of your Windows start menu, although I've never tried this.

Comment: This is just another waste of system resources. Looping sucks.