# Can a file copy be detected on windows?

Tags: windows, operating-system, copy

I want to trigger a piece of code to run as soon as a 'copy' command is executed on Windows. Let's say I want to perform some operations as soon as the user tries to copy a file. Is there any way to detect the 'copy' operation on Windows?

Comment: Copying is not an atomic operation that can be identified and monitored at the file-system level. It's simply reading the file data and some or all metadata.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. That's what anti-malware software does. What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You may monitor the clipboard (see [Creating a Clipboard Format Listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#creating-a-clipboard-format-listener)) and check if there is an object with format [CF_HDROP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) in it. But it will not tell you when the clipboard paste operation actually started.

This also will not cover copying which does not involve clipboard, like direct file_read/file_write loop in a [File Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager) application. For this you may monitor changes in the file system (see [How can I monitor a Windows directory for changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760904/how-can-i-monitor-a-windows-directory-for-changes)) but it will not tell you where was the file copied from, just where was it pasted to.